# http header ajax range gives always full site

Tags: javascript, http-headers, range, greasemonkey

I tried to send a request within a Greasemonkey script, using the Range-header.
The requested site is kind of long and I know which parts I actually need, so I thought, instead of requesting the whole site to download I could just request the necessary 500 bytes to speed things up.

However, `Range: bytes=0-500` always gives me the full website. I also tried `Content-Range: bytes=0-500`, which doesn't work, and `Content-Length:500` which isn't allowed to set any more due to security-problems.

So, does anybody know, why it is like this?
I'm using Greasemonkey scripts:

```
 GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "http://colonel-strawberry.deviantart.com/",
     headers: {"Range": "bytes=0-500"}, 
    onload: function (responseDetails) {
      console.log(responseDetails);
    },
    onerror: function(responseDetails) {
      console.log("err:"+responseDetails);
    }
});
```

With response-header:

```
Date: Mon, 05 Nov 2012 17:11:42 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP COR CURa OUR STP"
Connection: Keep-Alive
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: private
Keep-Alive: timeout=45
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The host `colonel-strawberry.deviantart.com` does not appear to support requests for byte ranges.

You would need to be requesting the data from a server that does support them.

(I tested by comparing `curl -H "Range: bytes=50-60" $foo` where `$foo` was first `http://colonel-strawberry.deviantart.com` and then where it was a URI on a server I do control).

Note [the HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2):

> A server MAY ignore the Range header.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarification. I already feared that. Does this mean I have to always load everything? Or is there another js/header method to only request a certain part of bytes or Dom?

Comment: @Julian, if the server won't play nice, then you can substring the response yourself with `responseDetails.responseText.substring (0, 500)`.  Alternatively, you can use DOM parsing on the whole response if it is a valid HTML doc (which it should be).  But search and/or ask a new question for that approach.

Comment: @BrockAdams , well, my goal was to speed up the rocess of getting the data. I wanted to decrease the amount of data that would have to be sended, so download-time would be shorter. This may not be a big problem on one request, but it is likely that there are about 50 requests of this sort... well, now I just have to rethink my concept. Dom-parsing is probably the slowest method on getting my needed information. indexOf and substring will work probably faster^^ But thanks for your advice!